# Frequence vs speed of a moving object

Tags: acoustics, frequency, aerodynamics, vibrations, vortex

Imagine swinging wood stick using hand (say it's a 1-meter long cylinder with 2 centimeter diameter, just for the sake of argument). When doing it fast (angular velocity = $\omega_1$), it will create a whooping sound. This sound has a frequency band ($f_{1,min}$ to $f_{1,max}$). To simplify, we assume the the band is really narrow and we use $f_1$ to denote this frequency.

Now assume we swing the rode twice faster $\omega_2$, where $\omega_2=2\omega_1$. What will be the frequence of the sound $f_2$? Will it be $f_2 = 2f_1$?

More assumptions, 1. the hand doesn't move, so there is no translational velocity. Only analyze the rotational velocity. 2. The speed of sound is constant.

My thought process: This acoustic sound is made from air molecule vibration. The air molecule's motion is caused by the rod compression. The faster the rod moves, the shorter the wavelength of the vibration. Since wavelength is inversely proportional to frequency (assuming the speed of sound is constant), then a twice faster rod results in a twice higher frequency. Based on Strouhal's research

$$
\mathrm{S}t = \frac{fL}{U},
$$

where $\mathrm{S}t$ is the Strouhal number. $f$ is the frequency of vortex shedding. $L$ is the characteristic length. $U$ is the flow velocity.

In my case, $f$ is the frequency of the whooping sound. $L$ is a constant when swinging the same rod. $U$ is the relative speed of the rod w.r.t the air. If $\mathrm{S}t$ is a constant, then I can conclude $f\propto U$.

Some reference states that $\mathrm{S}t\approx 0.2$. But does it change? If it changes, in what situation this change can be neglected?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: My reference, "Acoustics" by Pierce (1989), states that "Experiments indicate that $St=0.13$ when $Re=50$ [here, $Re$ is the Reynolds number], it increases to 0.2 at $Re=300$, and thereafter remains nearly constant up to $Re\approx10^4$.  Thereafter the sound is not narrow-band, so the identification of a unique Strouhal number becomes difficult." (Page 544)